# Failed to fetch update on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)

Tags: ubuntu, updates, ubuntu-14.04, apt-get

While running the update at Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr). The following error is being encountered:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/ is better place for this question

Comment: Got it. Moved to [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com) :)

Comment: FWIW, I just hit this exact error when bringing up a 14.04 based VM.  Simply restarting the VM setup from scratch got past the problem, but it does seem there's potential for an ephemeral failure here.  It'd be nice either for Ubuntu to isolate and fix this, or else to understand what's going on so provisioning scripts can work around it.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
apt-get update
```

Hope it helps someone else.
Cheers!

Comment: sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf

Answer (score 6):

There are many problem due to which this issue has come. Some of then are :

1. Any entry in you apt.list is not working. You or any application has created a wrong entry.
2. apt repository are not currently working.
3. Corrupt in /var/lib/apt/lists/ folder.

So for both of them there are different solution, if you didn't know the exact problem then follow following steps:

1. Use another mirrors of apt. In ubuntu there is file name `/etc/apt/sources.list` and folder containing some files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. So, from there you can change use any other mirrors of apt. Like you can change your India repository to US repository, etc. by editing these files.
2. There is another possibility too that you having any other repository link (third party) which is not responding for the moment. So, you can also delete them from the above given files. You can also remove all third party repositories from list

   rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
3. Remove all contents from `/var/lib/apt/lists/`

   rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

Comment: Thanks @varun-palekar, that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Something is up with the us.archive.ubuntu.com server.

I fixed it by changing all of the us.archive.ubuntu.com urls to in.archive.ubuntu.com in /etc/apt/sources.list

I used vim with find and replace like this:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
:%s/us.archive/in.archive/g
:wq
```

Answer (score 2):

The following command should work

```
sed -i -re 's/\w+\.archive\.ubuntu\.com/archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Thanks, the answer helps me to fix problem

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on my ubuntu on virtualbox before. I tried all above but that won't help.

When I worked on other backup script and I recognized that my server had incorrect date/time. I have [change](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3375/how-to-change-time-zone-settings-from-the-command-line) that and the apt-get update works like a charm.